# react native image with resizeMode contain, move inside the sub container

Tags: image, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flexbox

I currently write a react native application,

And I want to show 2 image at the top of my component, 
So I use my image with:

```
resizeMode:'contain'
```

Ah it works, but when I use it, it create a subcontainer and create a marge between the top of my component and my image

How I can remove this space ?

I have tried to remove the size of the space, but it don't works on all devices ...

Comment: You could use `resizeMode: 'cover'`, but you would lose a part of your image. A better option, but more complicated, would be to set the height of your image according to the current width in order to keep the same ratio as your original image.

Comment: @AntoineGrandchamp Thanks for your reply this is what is currently made actually but if I set the height, it looks like a little different between devices, I'm very intresting because I think there no way to do what I want exactly

Comment: What you can do is use [Dimension.get('window')](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions.html#get) to get the width of the view. Then, if you know that your original image dimensions are 500 x 250, and the view's width is 400px for exemple, you can then set your heigth to 200px.